# speeden up function using numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

```
from numba import jit

@jit
def interim_mk(x, unique_x):
    """

    :param x:
    :param unique_x:
    :return:
    """
    tp = np.zeros(unique_x.shape)

    for i in range(len(unique_x)):
        tp[i] = sum(x == unique_x[i])

    return tp
```

In the function above, I used jit to try and speeden it up. However, it does not seem to help. Both x and unique_x are numpy arrays, is there a way to speeden up this calculation (without using cython)

Comment: Is `unique_x = np.unique(x)`?

Comment: @Divakar, yes it is

Comment: For more meaningful answers, it would be helpful to clarify the intent of your function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### For case with positive numbers

You can use [`np.bincount`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) -

```
count = np.bincount(x)
out = count[count!=0]
```

Using `unique_x` -

```
out = np.bincount(x)[unique_x]
```

#### For generic case

```
out = np.bincount(np.searchsorted(unique_x, x))
```

---

Of course, we could have gotten the counts directly from `np.unique` call, if that's how we had `unique_x` -

```
out = np.unique(x, return_counts=1)[1]
```